# How to report progress of a web service on windows mobile client?

Tags: web-services, windows-mobile, soap-client, web-services-enhancements

I have tried to implement progress reporting using a soap extension as described at the following links:

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135478/how-do-you-measure-the-progress-of-a-web-service-call)
[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/Soap_Extension_Progress.aspx)

However, my "ProgressUpdate" method is not being called, and I believe that is because I haven't got an app.config file in my Windows Mobile project to tell the web service calls to be processed by the SOAP Extension. How can do it in Windows Mobile? This is the sample config file used in the article:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <webServices>
         <soapExtensionTypes> <add
        type="SoapExtensionLib.ProgressExtension, SoapExtensionLib"
        priority="1"  group="High" />
         </soapExtensionTypes>
      </webServices>
   </system.web> 

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this by adding a custom attribute to the method inside the generated proxy class. The custom attribute is derived from SoapExtensionAttribute.

I got the information at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esw638yk(VS.71).aspx)

Problem now is that I have to remember to add the attribute back in if I refresh the web service reference..............