# How to return status information during lengthy batch process in MVC 4 action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, batch-processing

In my MVC 4 app, I have a view that uploads a file from the client machine with:

```
<snip>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Batch", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input class="full-width" type="file" name="BatchFile" id="BatchFile" 
    <input type="submit" value="Do It" />
}
<snip>
```

The "Batch" action in the home controller takes that file and processes it in a way that may be very lengthy.... minutes even:

```
<snip>
[HttpPost]
public FileResult Batch(ModelType modelInstance)
{
    // Do the batch work.
    string result = LengthyBatchProcess(modelInstance.BatchFile.InputStream)
    var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(result);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=download.csv");
    return File(byteArray, "application/csv");
}
<snip>
```

This all works fine, and it isn't an inherent problem that the user is locked out for the time it takes for the batch process to run.  In fact they expect it.  The problem is that the user may not be in a position to know whether this process will take a couple of seconds or a couple of minutes, and I would like to provide them with status information while LengthyBatchProcess is running.  I have researched unobtrusive ajax, but it does not seem to have the functionality necessary for this, unless there is some way to chain unobtrusive ajax calls.  Any thoughts on how to best architect this?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve requires a bit of work.

One way is to open another channel (ajax call) to get the progress report. Quoting from [How do you measure the progress of a web service call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135478/how-do-you-measure-the-progress-of-a-web-service-call):

> Write a separate method on the server that you can query by passing the ID of the job that has been scheduled and which returns an approximate value between 0-100 (or 0.0 and 1.0, or whatever) of how far along it is.

I've found [a great tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/seanmcalinden/archive/2009/11/15/asynchronous-processing-in-asp-net-mvc-with-ajax-progress-bar.aspx) on this matter.

Comment: The tutorial looks great and I can't wait to try it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can start downloading the file in chuncks so the user can see the download progress of the browser:

```
try
{
   // Do the batch work.
   string result = LengthyBatchProcess(modelInstance.BatchFile.InputStream)
   var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
   Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(result);

   Response.Clear();
   Response.ClearContent();
   Response.Buffer = true;
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                      "attachment;filename=download.csv");
   Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
   Response.BufferOutput = false;

   for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
   {
        if (i % 10000 == 0)
        {
             Response.Flush();
        }

   Response.Output.WriteLine(byteArray[i]);
   }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 }
 finally
 {
   Response.Flush();
   Response.End();
 }
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but I don't think it would work as written, as it would only show the progress of output buffered during the file download.  Instead, the response would have to be written out during the batch process itself, which might be possible to do, but would take some substantive re-factoring of code in my case.  But I do appreciate the idea.  Thanks.

Comment: You said :'This all works fine, and it isn't an inherent problem that the user is locked out for the time it takes for the batch process to run. In fact they expect it.'
So consider if refactoring worths the effort.
You can change the mouse pointer to 'busy' or on click show some gif animation.
Most of the time when user knows she's doing a lengthy operation and some indication is shown for that - they're satisfied :)